# Properties of Estimators Using Dice Rolls?

Tags: probability, estimation, maximum-likelihood, mean

I am an MBA student taking courses in statistics.

Today, some of the students from the actual statistics faculty presented a seminar on estimation and probability - it was really interesting! In our own class, we have been learning about concepts such as the "Expected Value" and "Maximum Likelihood", and in this seminar we learned a bit about properties of these estimators. (As a note - we are learning how to write the Log Likelihood for different Probability Distributions, take the derivative, set them to 0 and solve the equations. I myself have taken undergrad courses in Calculus and Algebra and find myself able to do the math required - but at times struggle to understand the intution behind what I am doing)

For example, today we covered 4 important properties of estimators - these are the notes I made:

- **Unbiasedness**: An estimator is said to unbiased if the expected value of the estimator minus the actual estimator is 0. If this difference is not 0, this difference is called the "bias"
- **Consistency**: An estimator is consistent if as the number of samples increase, the value of the estimator becomes closer to the actual estimator.
- **Sufficiency**: An estimator is sufficient if no other estimator provides more information than this estimator.
- **Efficiency**: Unfortunately, I could not understand what the efficiency of an estimator is and why this is important. I read the Wikipedia page for this, and it seems to be related to the Fisher Information (and the Fisher Information appears to be a function of the likelihood).

Based on these notes, I tried to conceptualize them using a "dice roll" as an example. However, I struggle to understand the following points. For example, consider a 6-sided die:

- If I take the Expected Value of a single die, the answer is 3.5. If I roll this die many times, the average of all rolls will become closer and closer to 3.5. This being said, I can not understand the difference between **Unbiasedness** and **Consistency** here? It seems like one implies the other and vice versa?
- If I roll this die many times - the "mean" will tell me what the average value was, the "median" will tell me what the median value was (i.e. more robust with respect to outliers), and the "mode" will tell me the most frequent value that appeared. The mean, median and mode are all different statistics that provide me with different information about this die (e.g. suppose someone rolled this die 1000 times and asked me to judge if this die was "rigged" or not - I could make use of the mean, median and mode of the results from these rolls). This being said, how do I decide which of these statistics provides the most information - which of these is **Sufficient**?
- Finally, I have no idea how this example of rolling a die and different statistics calculated from the results will relate to **Efficiency**

Could someone please help me unpack all this information?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to be a bit more rigorous. Suppose you are considering a sequence of random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$. For instance: $X_i =$ the result of the $i$-th roll.

Up to now, no data is involved, i.e., we do not actually observe $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, just know that these are the random variables we're studying.
Performing an experiment means actually rolling the dice $n$ times and observing values $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, e.g., $(1, 3, ... , 2)$.

The properties of the estimators are studied without actually considering the result of the experiment.

Now, let me give an example of an unbiased estimator which is not consistent:
take as an estimator for the mean the outcome of the first roll. Since the rolls are independent and identically distributed, $E[X_1] = 3.5$. Hence, this estimator is unbiased.
However, no matter the sample size $n$, the estimator for the mean will always be $x_1$ which is always different from $3.5$.

Instead, consider as estimator for the mean
$$
\hat \mu_n := \frac{1}{n} \sum X_i + 1/n
$$
we have that $E[\hat \mu_n] = 3.5 + 1/n$, so that for any fixed $n$, the estimator is biased.
However, letting $n \rightarrow \infty$ $E[\hat \mu_n] \rightarrow 3.5$, moreover its variance shrinks to zero. In fact, you can check that
$$
Var[\hat \mu_n] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum Var[X_i] = \frac{1}{n} \frac{105}{36}
$$
which shows that, as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $Var[\hat \mu_n] \rightarrow 0$.
Thus, we have that the mean of $\hat \mu_n$ converges to the correct value while its variance shrinks to zero. In other words, we have that $\hat \mu_n$ will converge (almost surely) to the correct value. It is thus consistent.

The concept of sufficiency is a tad more complex. None of the statistics you cited is actually sufficient for dice rolls: you're missing the information about the variability of the rolls.
To decide if the dice is fair, you should perform a *test*, see for instance here: https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/gj70x/how_do_you_check_if_a_die_is_fair/

Finally, efficiency is used to compare different estimators. Suppose you have two consistent estimators $\hat \mu$ and $\hat \mu_2$. Which one do you use to draw your conclusions?

Up to now, we have seen estimators as random variables (the outcome of the experiment is never considered). But if you want to make decisions, you need to plug in those numbers. Suppose that when you plug in the data into $\hat \mu_1$ you get 3.7 and when you plug in the data into $\hat \mu_2$ you get $3.1$. How do you decide?
A solution is to pick the most efficient estimator: You pick the one with the lowest variance, because for a fixed sample size $n$, you can be more certain about the conclusion you get.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I think I understood most of this!

Comment: No problem :) you coul accept my answer as solution then!